# Retrieve the name from table based on matching Pattern through SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle11g

I have table name called Student which have following column and their values

```
roll_no      name       marks
123          rabes      80
567          baban      78
798          rees       98
345          tem        89
321          tom        82
987          lakhen     95
787          Mekkan     92
```

I want to filter the name of student which has only a or only e or both together. I have written the query like:

**SQL:** `select name from Student where name like '%a%' and name like '%e%'`

Output for the query:

```
roll_no      name       marks
123          rabes      80
567          baban      78
798          rees       98
345          tem        89
987          lakhen     95
787          Mekkan     92
```

Above approach is working fine for me, but I want the query with single matching pattern(using single like). Consider roll_no is a primary key. Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use wildcard ([pattern matching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html)),

```
SELECT DISTINCT name from `Student` WHERE `name` REGEXP '[ae]'
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but there one more requirement like in name the order of 'a' and 'e' can also be interchanged..I have edited the query.. please refer that

Comment: I have updated my answer. Let me know if you still face any issue

Comment: Still I'm facing the same issue i.e, 0 row selected

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this :

```
   select name from Student  where name like '%[ae]'
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but it is not working... as there is no error but there is 0 row selected...suggest some other approach

Comment: Please check my updated code :
select name from Student  where name like '%[ae]'

Comment: Please check that and let me know is its working fine or not.